# Saving array into multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Hey how could I save array into multiple row in database please? I am using mysql database with php.

```
// GETTING ALL THE B NODE STUFFS AND PRINTING IT'S CONTENTS
    $result = array();
    foreach($document->getElementsByTagName('b') as $node){
    $result[preg_replace('/:\s+$/','',$node->textContent)] = trim($node->nextSibling->textContent);

    }
    var_dump($result);
```

Here is the result am pulling from my array.

```
array
 'Choose by Subject Category or Module Code' => string '' (length=0)
 '
Back to Home page' => string '' (length=0)
 'International' => string 'visiting students should consult the' (length=36)
 'Undergraduate' => string 'students should refer to the relevant section of the UCC' (length=56)
 'Postgraduate' => string 'students should refer to the relevant section of the UCC' (length=56)
 'Credit Weighting' => string '5' (length=1)
 'Teaching Period(s)' => string 'Teaching Period 1.' (length=18)
 'No. of Students' => string 'Min 15, Max 30.' (length=15)
 'Pre-requisite(s)' => string 'None' (length=4)
 'Co-requisite(s)' => string 'None' (length=4)
 'Teaching Methods' => string '1 x 4hr(s) Lectures; Other (Distance Education Module - Up to 146hrs Self Directed Study).' (length=90)
 'Module Co-ordinator' => string 'Dr Peter Cleary, Department of Accounting, Finance and Information Systems.' (length=75)
 'Lecturer(s)' => string 'Staff, Department of Accounting, Finance and Information Systems.' (length=65)
 'Module Objective' => string 'To examine the management uses of accounting information and to enhance students ability to exert effective managerial control.' (length=127)
 'Module Content' => string 'Topics include; the accounting information needs of management, costs and pricing; estimating costs; the identification of key performance indicators; budgeting for control; capital investment appraisal and  implications for strategic planning and control.' (length=256)
 'Learning Outcomes' => string 'On successful completion of this module, students should be able to:' (length=68)
 'Assessment' => string 'Total Marks 100: Continuous Assessment 100 marks (Project/ Essay. Approximately 1500 words.).' (length=93)
 'Compulsory Elements' => string 'Continuous Assessment.' (length=22)
 'Penalties (for late submission of Course/Project Work etc.)' => string 'Where work is submitted up to and including 7 days late, 10% of the total marks available shall be deducted from the mark achieved.  Where work is submitted up to and including 14 days late, 20% of the total marks available shall be deducted from the mark achieved.  Work submitted 15 days late or more shall be assigned a mark of zero.' (length=336)
 'Pass Standard and any Special Requirements for Passing Module' => string '40%.' (length=4)
 'End of Year Written Examination Profile' => string 'No End of Year Written Examination.' (length=35)
 'Requirements for Supplemental Examination' => string 'Marks in passed element(s) of Continuous Assessment are carried forward, Failed element(s) of Continuous Assessment must be repeated (Resubmission of revised Continuous Assessment).' (length=181)
```

I did try a for each statement with NSERT query inside but all the content was saved in a colum instead.

```
$array_data = implode("array_separator", $result);
    foreach($result as $snode){
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO save_array (ModuleCode) VALUES ('%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($snode));
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
    echo $snode.<br />';
    }
    echo '<br /><br /><br />';
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 //============== LATEST INSERT QUERY================//     
$array_data = implode("array_separator", $result); 
foreach($result as $snode){ 
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO save_array 
       (ModuleCode,
        Homepage,
        International,
        Undergraduate,
        Postgraduate,
        CreditWeighting,
        TeachingPeriod,
        NoofStudents,
        Prerequisite,
        Corequisite,
        TeachingMethods,
        ModuleCoordinator,
        Lecturer,
        ModuleObjective,
        ModuleContent,
        LearningOutcomes,
        Assessment,
        CompulsoryElements,
        Penalties,
        PassStandard,
        EndofYearWrittenExamination,
        RequirementsforExamination) VALUES ('%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($snode)); 


foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
$query = $query . "$value"; 

 echo '<br /><br />'; 
mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());  
echo $snode. '<br />'; 
}
echo '<br /><br /><br />';
```

Comment: sidenote: try using [mysqli](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) functions (or PDO) instead of old [mysql](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), they will be removed soon.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer would be to iterate through a foreach loop, concatenating the values into an INSERT query (for more information, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), and have the foreach loop exclude the keys "Undergraduate", "International", and "Postdoc", as well as any values that have length 0.

Your problem seems to be in the INSERT query.  Try something like this:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO save_array (CreditWeighting, TeachingPeriod, NoofStudents, etc.)) VALUES ('%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($snode));

foreach ($result as $key => $value)
    $query = $query . "$value";
```

And do some tweaking to get the query string just right.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.What I meant by by multiple row is each and every value is inserted into a different row as I'll be doing this for alot of data and want all the data that's extracted in the array to be saved seperately. Not sure maybe I explained that properly.

Comment: It looks like you just need key-value pair table, but in that case you're going to lose a lot of information.  Do you have a schema (database table definition) that you're using?

Comment: I added my schema to the code that I editied above.Please have a look at it.

Comment: Answer edited, take a look at it. Unfortunately I don't have the time to get all of the intricacies of the query formation correct, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you alot.I'll give that ago and let you know how I get on.

Comment: @user1444442 Echo your query and see what it looks like. It's seems you have a some sort of problem separating your array values. (Your `International` and `Undergraduate` strings are not separated. Your error message: "visiting students should consult **thestudents** should refer to the relevant sectio").

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on all elements of array and prepare SQL INSERT INTO statment, and when you do this execute it.

Comment: I did try but all keep going in just one column.I have a sample code I did above.